# Why does gtest does not like my expression?

Tags: c++, googletest

I experienced a strange error message from gtest. Compiling

```
EXPECT_EQ(MyVal,0xe-2);
```

results in error message:

```
unable to find numeric literal operator 'operator"" -2'
```

while

```
EXPECT_EQ(MyVal,0xe -2);
```

and

```
EXPECT_EQ(MyVal,0xf-2);
```

compile fine. Any ideas? (Maybe it attempts to exponentiate??)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic C/C++ gotcha.

`0xe-2` is a `pp-number` (*preprocessing number*) token because:

- it starts with a digit,
- consists of digits and letters, except for
- a `-` following an `e`.

So it is a single token. However, the token does not correspond to any numeric literal, so it is not a valid token after preprocessing.

By contrast, `0xf-2` is three tokens: `0xf`, `-`, and `2`, and all three are valid after preprocessing.

It is always better to put white space around operators. Whitespace characters are very affordable.

Comment: Till now, I considered, that C++ !generally! ignores white space. Where can I find the cases, when NOT ?

Comment: Thanks, although I do not completely understand it. If it is one token, why the processing looks for operator? If the preprocessing considers exceptions like 'e-2', and the result is wrong; why not attempt to interpret analogously with 'f-2'? In the way shown, a legal expression is evaluated as false, because of an inconsequent preprocessor.

Comment: The `literal operator""` error refers to a C++11 feature which allows user-defined literal conversion operators which are strings appended to numeric literals (like the length and sign suffixes). Afaik, a literal operator needs to start with a letter or `$`, so the error message is a little odd. As to why it doesn't try a different lex, the only answer is "because that's what the standard says". However, C++ never tries to figure out what you might have meant, so it is consistent.

Comment: @katang: white space is significant when it separates two tokens which would otherwise be considered one token. For example, `xy` is different from `x y` and `2e1` is different from `2 e1`. (Another example: consider what happens when you leave the spaces out of `y = x / *ptr;`) There are some other cases in the preprocessor: line ending with directives and function-like macro definitions.